# What is the process ubuntu-ge?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I issued at the terminal

```
sudo lsof -i
```

And one of the process listed was **ubuntu-ge** which was in CLOSE_WAIT state to canonical.com. My guess is that it's the updater process.

By the way, I'm on a Ubuntu x64 12.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It allows 32-bit systems to use up to 64GB of RAM. Normally, they would only be able to use up to 4GB.

Comment: It's strange to have this process running on a 64bit Ubuntu. But thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is probably `ubuntu-geoip-provider` process, not just `ubuntu-ge`. You can try

```
ps aux | grep ubuntu-ge
```

and ensure that `ubuntu-geoip-provider` process has the same pid as shown by `lsof`. You can read more about `ubuntu-geoip-provider` from an [AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135602/i-have-permanent-connections-to-canonical-servers-what-are-they-for-and-how-can).